# Shiny Slider Customized Values

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to set custom values for shiny slider (1,5,10,15,20,25 and 30). I tried `step` but then the results either (0,5,10,15,20,25,30) or (1,6,11,16,21,26,31). Is there any way yo define custom values for slider?
Thanks!

```
plotpath <- "/Volumes/share-ites-1-$/Projects/Scientifica/Simulations_Scientifica"

ui <- fluidPage(
     titlePanel("LandClim Simulations"),
     sidebarLayout(
          sidebarPanel(
               sliderInput(inputId = "temp", 
                           label = "Temperature increase:", 
                           value = 1, min = 1, max = 2,
                           step = 1, animate = TRUE ),
               sliderInput(inputId = "prec", 
                           label = "Precipitation change:", 
                           value = 0, min = -2, max = 2,
                           step = 1, animate = TRUE ),
               sliderInput(inputId = "decade", 
                           label = "Time (decade):", 
                           value = 1, min = 0, max = 30,
                           step = 5, animate = TRUE )
          ),
          mainPanel(imageOutput("image")) 
     )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
     output$image <- renderImage( deleteFile = FALSE, {
               return(list(
                    src = paste(plotpath,"/Temp",input$temp,"Prec",input$prec,"Dec",input$decade,".png",sep = ""),
                    contentType = "image/png"))
     } ) }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `shinyWidgets` package now solves this for you with a slider that allows custom values. Updated code for your third slider would look like this:

```
shinyWidgets::sliderTextInput(inputId = "decade", 
  label = "Time (decade):", 
  choices = c(1,5,10,15,20,25,30))
```

Answer (score 0):

Although Shiny gives options to customize the slider Input,I do not think there is a way to to get output in the form (1,5,10...).This is because the difference between your 1st and 2nd point is 4 and thereafter it is 5 which will be inconsistent with the way step parameter works.Step can only generate numbers based on constant differences between slider inputs.

Comment: I know step can't solve my problem but I think there is no other way to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the need to have a slider, to have inputs with variable breaks you could use one of the other options, like

selectInput

https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/selectInput.html

or even checkboxInput

https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/checkboxInput.html

Comment: I need to use sliders.

Comment: fair enough. if you put 'sliderInput' into the terminal you can get the function details, find the line which starts with   "step <- findStepSize(min, max, step)" which is where the step is calculated and override with your step values. not a clean answer but workable.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done using sliderTextInput function in shiny. No need to add all this complex js function. Just a few lines of code will do the trick.Install the shinywidgets package which contains the sliderTextInput function. Do the following :

```
  sliderTextInput("decade","Time (decade):, 
                  choices = c(1,5,10,15,20,25,30), 
                  selected = c(1,5,10,15,20,25,30), 
                  animate = FALSE, grid = FALSE, 
                  hide_min_max = FALSE, from_fixed = FALSE,
                  to_fixed = FALSE, from_min = NULL, from_max = NULL, to_min = NULL,
                  to_max = NULL, force_edges = FALSE, width = NULL, pre = NULL,
                  post = NULL, dragRange = TRUE)
```