# Need to have two different steps in a single slider

Tags: r, shiny, slider, shinydashboard

I am building a shiny dashboard in R Shiny where i need to include a slider with 2 different 'steps'

What i need is the slider from 0-10 in increments of 1

i.e.: `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`

and then from 11-30 in increments of 5 i.e.: `11-15, 16-20, 21-25, 26-30`

Is there a way for me to take care of the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/45776668/680068

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shiny Slider Customized Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776668/shiny-slider-customized-values)

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that you want the slider to show ranges for the second set of values?

Comment: Thanks @phalteman this helps.. If say i had to have a range up to 500 then how would i be able to do so? For example if i had to have 1 - 200 in increments of 1 and then 201 -500 in increments of 5.. then it would not be feasable for me to manually insert all the options.. is there a way i can handle this'?

Comment: @phalteman is there some way to include a `step` argument to the `seq` in the  `choices = c(seq(1,10), "11-15", "16-20", "21-25", "26-30"))` statement that you have included in your answer?

Comment: @Roosh, you can use the `by=` argument in `seq()` to help define the step. See edit below to address your earlier comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this is a very similar question to others asked on the site, and the answer is also quite similar. However, note that while `sliderTextInput()` will allow you to display the values you want to see, you will have to deal with data of different types:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderTextInput(inputId = "values", 
                  label = "Values:", 
                  choices = c(seq(1,10), "11-15", "16-20", "21-25", "26-30")),
  sliderTextInput(inputId = "values2", 
                  label = "Values:", 
                  choices = c(seq(1,100,by=1), seq(105,500,by=5))),
  verbatimTextOutput("sliderval"),
  verbatimTextOutput("sliderval2")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$sliderval <- renderText({paste("Slider 1", input$values, class(input$values), sep="; ")})
  output$sliderval2 <- renderText({paste("Slider 2", input$values2, class(input$values2), sep="; ")})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```